# Does anyone know how to make the plastic part of a blister pack used in the medical packaging?

Tags: objects

[image: Image for reference]

How do you make it all as one seamless object? The pills and the base are both separate elements so that's not an issue.

Comment: hello, could you please tell a bit more about the difficulty you meet?

Comment: Well, im new to blender and i didnt know where to begin and how to get the curve at the bottom of the plastic bit. but looking at these other comments, ive gotten my answer. thanks though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a plane

Subdivide it 3 times

[image]

Select the vertices in the center ring and do mesh > tranform > "to sphere" and move the mouse to create an octagon.

[image]

Extrude the center

[image]

Add a subsurf modifier

[image]

set the shading to smooth

[image]

To have sharper edges add a  couple of loop cuts

[image]

Select the outer edges and then select Edge > Crease and set the crease to 1.0 to make the outer edges sharp.

[image]

Add a couple of array modifiers

[image]

[image]

Comment: Identical to mine! So, just a P.S. .. I put bevel weights instead of creases to get a sharper top circumference bevel than bottom, and a couple of insets in the top face, prop. raised spherically to make a dome on top.. yours is cheaper, poly-wise.. You can also use an end-cap and mirror to make the sheet with a gulley in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

You could try [instancing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/index.html#instancing) if you don't mind the base being separate from the pill.

A relatively simple process, model a pill from a circle, and parent <kbd>P</kbd> that to a grid or plane object that is set as an instancer (set to [faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/faces.html#faces)).

If you require afterwards to have indiviual control of the instances, you may [make them "real"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html#make-instances-real) with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

See the below gif for an example of usage:

[image]

<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>