# Model a clamshell or blister packaging from retail stores

Tags: modeling

I'm looking for what you see on hooks in a store. I've just started to use Blender for all my 3d modeling so forgive me if I'm not being clear.

The photos are what I'm trying to recreate.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting us to do. Without knowing where exactly you are stuck or what you have tried so far there's nothing I can help with. These are not even the same kind of packaging. The left one is a card with a transparent plastic shell glued on top of it, the other one is a card hot sealed between a front and back plastic hull. Try to model the shapes of those parts, then you have to make materials for them, probably with image textures for the cards and a transmissive material for the plastic.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125116/how-to-do-vaccuum-sealed-pack-modeling-in-blender/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78769/how-to-create-vacuum-packaging https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194246/does-anyone-know-how-to-make-the-plastic-part-of-a-blister-pack-used-in-the-medi https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231764/how-can-i-simulate-thermoforming/

Answer (score 0):

As to such packaging you add eg a cylinder, remove bottom face, array it first X then Y by the same **relative** offset. Then you add "the bottom" cube, align it with  cylinders arrayed and combine the two. Done, you modeled a nice calculator cell or tablets package
[image]
If you want a package as that STANLEY you showed, you make the tools outlines, knife project and extrude them.
[image]

Comment: thank you, I'm new to Blender and you've pointed me in the right direction, thank you.